# How can I combine 2 columns in python

Tags: python, numpy

so I have an array with 5 columns that looks like this

```
1 MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS  
2 MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS  
3 MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS  
4 MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

And I want to combine columns 2 and 3 and then 4 and 5 so I have a resulting array looking like

```
1 MM-DD-YYYYHH:MM:SS MM-DD-YYYYHH:MM:SS  
2 MM-DD-YYYYHH:MM:SS MM-DD-YYYYHH:MM:SS  
3 MM-DD-YYYYHH:MM:SS MM-DD-YYYYHH:MM:SS  
4 MM-DD-YYYYHH:MM:SS MM-DD-YYYYHH:MM:SS
```

is there a way to do this using numpy without the use of pandas?
Thanks

Comment: `numpy.hstack` ?

Comment: Why not use Pandas?